# JSP Dropdown List with Blank Default

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP Dropdown that is populated from a database query, and it is working just fine.

But I want to also add a blank default option so that the field is empty when submitted.  Right now the default is the first value selected from the database.  But I want it to appear empty.

The only way I've gotten it to work is to manually add a **`""`** to the list as it is being populated.

Is there a more elegant way of doing that?

```
        <div class="row">
            <label class="span2">Action</label>
            <form:select path="Action">
                <form:options items="${actionList}" />
                <form:errors path="Action" cssClass="error"/>
            </form:select>
        </div>
```

Page with default values, which I do not want to appear by default:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use single option element

```
<form:select path="Action" >
    <form:option  value="" />
    <form:options items="${actionList}" />
    <form:errors  path="Action" cssClass="error"/>
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 1):

An empty default is no good UI-Design. You should give a hint what to do.

```
    <div class="row">
        <label class="span2">Action</label>
        <form:select path="Action">
            <option selected="selected"> -- Please choose --</option>
            <form:options items="${actionList}" />
            <form:errors path="Action" cssClass="error"/>
        </form:select>
    </div>
```

Or better html is

```
    <div class="row">
        <label class="span2">Action
            <form:select path="Action">
                <option selected="selected"> -- Please choose --</option>
                <form:options items="${actionList}" />
                <form:errors path="Action" cssClass="error"/>
            </form:select>
        </label>
    </div>
```

If you like to style it like a table, you should remove the div, style the label as display:table-cell and ...

Answer (score 0):

As the first answer is not particularly UX friendly and the second answer is not very spring-y :/

Combining both the previous answers would give best of both worlds:

```
<form:select path="Action" >
  <form:option  value="">--Select one--</form:option>
  <form:options items="${actionList}" />
  <form:errors  path="Action" cssClass="error"/>
</form:select>
```

and this will store a null value in the database.